# Task not serializable at Spark

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I have a transformation as like that:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Long>> mappedRdd = myRDD.values().map(
    new Function<Pageview, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Long> call(Pageview pageview) throws Exception {
        String key = pageview.getUrl().toString();
        Long value = getDay(pageview.getTimestamp());
        return new Tuple2<>(key, value);
      }
    });
```

Pageview is a type of: [Pageview.java](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/gora-tutorial/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/tutorial/log/generated/Pageview.java)

and I register that class into Spark as like that:

```
Class[] c = new Class[1];
c[0] = Pageview.class;
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(c);
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark.run(ExampleSpark.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark.main(ExampleSpark.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark, value:
>   org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark@1a2b4497)
>     - field (class: org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark$1, name: this$0, type: class org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark)
>     - object (class org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark$1, org.apache.gora.tutorial.log.ExampleSpark$1@4ab2775d)
>     - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1,
>   name: fun$1, type: interface
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
>     - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
>     ... 7 more

When I debug the code I see that `JavaSerializer.scala` is called even there is a class named `KryoSerializer`.

**PS 1:** I don't wanna use Java Serializer but implementing `Serializer` at `Pageview` does not solve the problem.

**PS 2:** This does not throw away the problem:

```
...
//String key = pageview.getUrl().toString();
//Long value = getDay(pageview.getTimestamp());
String key = "Dummy";
Long value = 1L;
return new Tuple2<>(key, value);
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this issue multiple times with Java code. Although I was using Java serialization, I would make the class that contains that code Serializable or if you don't want to do that I would make the Function a static member of the class.

Here is a code snippet of a solution.

```
public class Test {
   private static Function s = new Function<Pageview, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {

     @Override
     public Tuple2<String, Long> call(Pageview pageview) throws Exception {
       String key = pageview.getUrl().toString();
       Long value = getDay(pageview.getTimestamp());
       return new Tuple2<>(key, value);
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: Class is at external package (not an inner class). Could you eloborate what you mean with making Function as a static member?

Comment: @kamaci Updated with code snippet. At work we usually did the above or made a method static that returned the instance of the function. Also the class I was referring to was the one that has your code snippet not the Pageview class.

Comment: It works! Does it use Kryo serialization at this version? Also, what has changed and it started to work?

Comment: @kamaci Reading another post on here regarding Java serialization the Function object that you changed to be static will not be serialized which is why it works.

You should be good using Kryo serialization on your classes like Pageview. Your issue was that the Function object couldn't be serialized.

I figured this would solve your issue as I've run into this countless number of times.

Comment: So, it seems that using Kyro serialization is more convenient way to handle it. I'll accept your answer. On the other hand how can I make my class Kyro serialized?

Comment: @kamaci I've never used Kryo before. Is there a similar interface like Java's Serializable? I would check on here if someone has already asked that question.

Here's Sparks documentation regarding Kryo and Data serialization if that helps: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/tuning.html

Comment: I didn't use Kyro too. Pageview.java uses Avro serialization.

Comment: Btw, here it is static also: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaLogQuery.java#L79   ?

Comment: @ColinMc  I am getting the same error, even i created as static function, i am trying to use JavaRDD foreach, inside foreach i am using FileWriter class from Java IO package, it says the FileWriter is not Serializable.

Comment: @Shankar Can you create a new question regarding your issue? Thanks! I will need to see the code to potentially help you.